# Cant Retrieve the values of Structure fields (i.e. text boxes) through Remix IDE

Tags: remix, struct

I am giving the values to structure field through Remix IDE, then I am putting ‘0’ as the index of people array, then I click transact and then I click call, but Remix does not show me the value I gave as input to the structure fields (encircled in blue box).
However, previously it worked:
[Understanding array of structure](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79092/problem-with-understanding-contract-containing-array-of-structure)
The code is:

```
    pragma solidity 0.5.4;
    contract MyContractOwnerAddr {
        uint256 public peopleCount = 0;
        mapping(uint => Person) public people;

        address owner;

        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }

        struct Person {
            uint _id;
            string _firstName;
            string _lastName;
        }

        constructor() public {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }

        function addPerson(
            string memory _firstName,
            string memory _lastName)
            public
            onlyOwner
        {
            incrementCount();
            people[peopleCount] = Person(peopleCount, _firstName, _lastName);
        }

        function incrementCount() internal {
            peopleCount += 1;
        }
    }
```

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.
[image: Problem with retrieving textbox values]

Comment: The code from your original post is still working in remix for me. Have you added or changed any code?If so please post. Have you changed the compiler version?

Comment: @Steven V I have added the code, kindly check it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increment people count is added before adding the person to the mapping. So nothing is added to the people[ 1 ] spot in the mapping. As is, the first spot in the mapping that gets filled is people[ 0 ]. Move `incrementCount()` to after adding the person to the mapping.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked after several tries. Why you put 0 in quotations? But I tired without quotations.

Comment: I only did because that’s what your screen shot had :) - normally I wouldn’t have. Seemed to work both ways for me.